# Difference between forking and cloning a GitHub repo

Tags: github, git-clone, git-fork

What is the difference between forking a GitHub repository and cloning it to my local machine?

I would like to contribute to an open source library and I think the easiest way is to clone the repository and then send a pull request to the owner of the library to be reviewed. But why do other people fork repositories?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to send a pull request using the Github user interface, you have to fork a repository. (By the way, this is done automatically for you if you just want to make a trivial string/doc change using the online "Edit" feature of GitHub.)

Forking and cloning a local copy are not mutually exclusive.

You would typically do both, to build and test locally, and when happy, commit and push up to your fork.

Comment: Thanks. If i just clone the project and then create a branch locally, make modification and then push it the owner's repository and then create a pull request to be merged to the master, can i do like this ?

Comment: You cannot push it to the owner's repository without their permission. By default, only the owner has permission to push to their repository. That is why we use forks.

Comment: Thanks it's clear for me.

Comment: "In order to send a pull request using the Github user interface, you have to fork a repository."  This is not true.  One can make a pull request that requests for a branch to be pulled into another branch even if both branches are a part of the same fork.

Comment: Sure but in the context of the question the repository to be modified is a repository that the questioner does not have commit access to.